# Standared WebCam interface for .NET besides DirectShow?

Tags: directshow, webcam, ocx

I want to be able to take still images with a web cam, via .NET 2.0 (or 3.5 if necessary). I know I can use DirectShow but that seems like a very large learning curve.

Is there a simple to use OCX, or library that can work with most standard webcams?

Comment: Did you see the following link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236249/simple-net-webcam-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegasus Imaging has the [CapturePRO](http://www.pegasusimaging.com/capturepro.htm) control.  It comes in both ActiveX and .NET (WinForms) versions.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Image Acqisition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368(VS.85).aspx) would be the standard, non direct show way to do this. (ie: non third-party).